# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'phonenumbers'

Tags: django

I am deploying an app which works well locally to Heroku for the first time, and I have the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'phonenumbers'

```
2021-08-01T05:05:10.359150+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2021-08-01T05:05:10.359151+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2021-08-01T05:05:10.359151+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2021-08-01T05:05:10.359152+00:00 app[web.1]: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2021-08-01T05:05:10.359152+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
2021-08-01T05:05:10.359152+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2021-08-01T05:05:10.359153+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2021-08-01T05:05:10.359153+00:00 app[web.1]: module = import_module(entry)
2021-08-01T05:05:10.359153+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2021-08-01T05:05:10.359154+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-08-01T05:05:10.359154+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2021-08-01T05:05:10.359155+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2021-08-01T05:05:10.359155+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-08-01T05:05:10.359221+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'phonenumbers'
2021-08-01T05:05:10.360272+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-01 05:05:10 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416411+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-01 05:05:10 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416412+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416413+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416413+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416414+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416414+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416415+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416415+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416419+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416420+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416420+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416421+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416421+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416421+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416422+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416422+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416423+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416423+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416424+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416424+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416425+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416425+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416426+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416426+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416427+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
2021-08-01T05:05:10.416427+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
```

When i try to install it phonenumbers again, it tells me that it is already installed.

I am quite new to Django/Python, coming from Ruby.
Is there a solution for this problem please ?
it works very well in development.

Comment: How you installed this package?

Comment: I am using the followingf : $ pip install phonenumbers
Requirement already satisfied: phonenumbers in /Users/renechan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (8.12.28)

Comment: And how do you use this package?

Comment: My understanding is that it is phonenumber_field module which is in my INSTALLED_APPS which calls for that phonenumber module.

Comment: Maybe you used this package: https://pypi.org/project/django-phonenumber-field/

Comment: yes that is the one that installed

Comment: you can use the 'pip freeze' command and check all installed packages.

Comment: The following show up: phonenumbers==8.12.28, django-phonenumber-field==5.1.0

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. pip install django-phonenumber-field
2. pip install django-phonenumbers

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably forgot to add 'phonenumbers' to INSTALLED_APP in settings.py

Comment: hi @Amin That is not the case, I have it in the installed_app as well as in the requirements.txt

Comment: and do you use pip3 install {PACKAGE} ? its important to use pip3 instead of pip for python3

Comment: pip3 install phonenumbers
Requirement already satisfied: phonenumbers in /Users/renechan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (8.12.28)

Comment: @ReneChan last thing i can say is that make sure you are in correct venv. make sure you run pip3 command in the same venv as you run project in

Comment: hey, sure I would do that, is the a function I can call to check that in Python please ?

Comment: I just tried the following : 
sys.prefix
'/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9'

Answer (score 1):

check on the bottom left on the tab phyton package that package. if not found
you have to make another phyton virtual environment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).